# Fibonacci in Python - Explain this code?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to coding and I have been using the book Python for beginners by Alex Bowers. At the end of each chapter is a lab exercise and this particular one was about Fabonacci and the chapter itself was about forLoops, whileLoops, Try Except and Finally, and Breaks and Continues.
I was confused about the solution especially the lines dealing with the variable "set", could anybody explain the solution to me because they do not explain it in the book... Thank you

```
f0 = 0
f1 = 1
set = False              
while True:
    fn = f0 + f1
    f0 = f1
    f1 = fn 
    if (fn > 100):
        set = True
    else:
        set = False
    print(fn)
    if (set == True):
        break
```

Comment: @thefourtheye: I don't think that's a reason for it to be off-topic. Can you justify that?

Comment: @Christian: The question is "How does this work?" How is it not specific? OP even mentiones what lines are particularly confusing to him/her

Comment: That `set` variable is just over complicating the code...

Comment: @NiklasB. I believe it is not specific and OP doesn't have basic understanding of the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Stack Overflow for is for specific questions you can't answer elsewhere. It isn't intended for basic programming questions, and I'm sure this has been answered elsewhere. Try looking for some basic information about programming in Python. The python documentation is fantastic: 

http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @thefourtheye: The question is in fact very specific. In my interpretation this falls under "question that covers a software algorithm".

Comment: @NiklasB. Okay I ll revoke my vote.

Comment: @Myles: Who told you it's not intended for basic programming questions? That's just absurd, the Help Center explicitely says that you can ask about general programming problems and algorithms here

Comment: @NiklasB. mmm, yes it may be specific. And just to clarify what MylesBaker (in my opinion) tried to say, is that questions like: *"What does `print` do in Python?"* should not be asked.

Comment: @Christian: I don't see why it shouldn't be asked, unless it has already been asked in a different question (and that tends to be the case for most trivial questions)

Comment: Calling a variable `set` is a very bad practice since it overrides object `set`; that is you can no longer make a `set` object.

Comment: It shouldn't be asked because it could be easily found in Python docs. [You could read this so you get the idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: If you look at the beginning of this wonderful resource you will find plenty of questions that are fairly straightforward which means they would be trivial to an experienced programmer.  A new user asks a really valid question from his perspective and a number of people beat him up.  That is one way to keep this community isolated.  I think you should be very careful about down voting a question from a new user.  If you don't like a question then go find one you like to contribute to or make a gentle suggestion to the OP about how to fix it.  Please I think this person deserves some respect

Comment: @PyNEwbie: I fully agree with you and I'm sometimes stunned by the elitism shown by this community.

Comment: @OP Please use a different book for learning, that example code is horrible.

Comment: thanks for some of the great answers! definitely helped clear up the confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you know what Fibonacci Sequence is (if not, read [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/fibonacci-sequence.html)).  I'll go at this step at a time

These are the variables used to calculate the Fibonacci Sequence.  `f0` being the first number in the sequence and `f1` being the second.

```
f0 = 0
f1 = 1
```

`set` will be used as a condition for the following loop to determine when to stop.

```
set = False
```

This is an infinite while loop.

```
while True:
```

Calculate the next number in the sequence.

```
    fn = f0 + f1
```

Update the older variables.

```
    f0 = f1
    f1 = fn
```

If you've gotten a number in the sequence that is greater than 100 set `set` to `True`.  Else set `set` to `False` (which it already is).

```
    if (fn > 100):
        set = True
    else:
        set = False
```

Print the current sequence number.

```
    print(fn)
```

If `set` is `True`, leave the infinite loop.

```
    if (set == True):
        break
```

**NOTE**:  This code can be easily simplified.  I'm surprised it's in a book.  You can simplify it to this:

```
f0 = 0
f1 = 1
while True:
    fn = f0 + f1
    f0 = f1
    f1 = fn 
    print(fn)
    if (fn > 100):
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

`set` in this case is stopping the loop once the number gets above `100`, so it doesn't go forever. This is actually a pretty terrible way of making a Fibonacci sequence, but I'll explain, since it's valid code anyhow...

```
f0 = 0 # initialize your
f1 = 1 # starting values
set = False              
while True:
    fn = f0 + f1 # fn is your current fib number
    f0 = f1 # advance the second-to-last number
    f1 = fn # and the last number
    if (fn > 100):
        set = True # if your current fib number is above 100, set a flag
                   # so we don't go another iteration
    else:
        set = False# otherwise, this should never ever do anything. This
                   # line of code does nothing but slow down the process
    print(fn) # print your current fib number to console
    if (set == True): # if that aforementioned flag is set...
        break         # then break out of the loop. Otherwise, loop.
```

For what it's worth, I would do:

```
fib = [1,1]
while True:
    num = fib[-1]+fib[-2]
    fib.append(num)
    # optionally:
    ## print(num)
    if num > 100: break
```

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Fair enough, I misread `fn > 100` as `fn >= 100`. Doesn't hardly change the broad strokes, though.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `set`, the code could be written this way to achieve the same thing in otherwise exactly the same way:

```
f0 = 0
f1 = 1
fn = 0
while fn <= 100:
    fn = f0 + f1
    f0 = f1
    f1 = fn 
    print(fn)
```

The use of `set` is an odd and long-winded alternative to using a proper loop condition (the `fn <= 100` bit), and is likely only in there to shoehorn in examples of if statements both with and without `else` clauses.

With some slightly more advanced logic that you might come across elsewhere in the book, you can also eliminate the `fn` variable:

```
f0 = 0
f1 = 1
while f0 <= 100:
    f0, f1 = f1, f0 + f1
    print(f0)
```

the line `f0, f1 = f1, f0 + f1` is similar to:

```
 f0 = f1
 f1 = f0 + f1
```

except that both right-hand side expressions are evaluated *before* either `f0` or `f1` changes value.

Hopefully seeing it written in this simplified form can help you to understand exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Hi sorry about your introduction to this forum.  It is generally really a fantastic resource but sometimes elitism takes over.

I think your question has not really been answered yet.

```
set = False # assigning a value to a name of a thing the thing is set and the value is False
while True:  # this means the loop will continue until it hits a return statement
```

The fact of the matter is that set does not have to be initialized outside the loop the loop will continue until some condition is met within the loop that will cause a return. In this case the condition is that the object named set has its value changed to True. I am not much of a programmer but this is really horrible code.

let me add that another issue with this is that set is a reserved word for a special type of object so that adds another black mark against the code.  When I typed the code in IDLE the word set was purple - that is a signal that you are moving into dangerous territory - using an object name or reserved word as the name of a variable